# LEFT function using SWITCH: "DAX Comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text."

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax

This is my first time posting to stackoverflow and have just broke into the PowerBI world yesterday since my company uses Access and VB code to write all reports and I have had enough of that.

I'm currently trying to create a new column that will write the series number. This can be achieved by using the first 2 or 4 digits of the PNUM. For example, series 20 would be denoted by either **20**03, **20**10 or RH**20**1564, CH**20**3456,etc. For my new column, I want all of those results to say 20.

Below is my current code for this column, using the LEFT function within the SWITCH. I do not understand when I'm getting this error mentioned in the title.

```
FormulaCode2 = 
SWITCH(
        LEFT('Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM],2 ="RH"),20,
        LEFT('Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM],2 ="ZR"),20,
        LEFT('Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM],2 ="CD"),20
        )
```

NOTE: At first I attempted the easiest way by trying to create a VAR of a list such as {"A".."z"} to capture all possible forms of a AA-zz that could appear in front of the series. However, I could not get very far. I wish DAX made use of wildcards, it would so much easier to put ??20 and just be done with it!

I'll appreciate any help with anyone that reads my long explanation. I hope to contribute back to this community and learn as much as I can! Thanks.

[The [PNUM] Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JF44.png)

Comment: this sort of transformations fits better with M/PowerQuery, why not use that? Can you give more examples (in the table format) of values in 'Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM]? Also those which shouldn't be qualified as 20 to avoid false positives

Comment: So, the column that I'm pulling from [PNUM] contains text and numbers. Since SWITCH and LEFT are not compatible with text, how would I be able to use PNUM as a reference to get my new series column?

I've added a picture of the PNUM column.

Comment: SWITCH works fine with text, the error is due to boolean instead of integer in LEFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off. The first argument of [SWITCH](https://dax.guide/switch/) is what to check against.

I think this is what you're trying to write.

```
FormulaCode2 =
SWITCH (
    LEFT ( 'Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM], 2 ),
    "RH", 20,
    "ZR", 20,
    "CD", 20
)
```

On the other hand, if you want to extract the 3rd and 4th characters, then you can use [MID](https://dax.guide/mid/) instead of LEFT.

```
MID ( 'Overall Product Portfolio Planning'[PNUM], 3, 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks! I lack some basic understanding when it comes to DAX code, I really appreciate helping me see have I was missing!